# How can I execute custom code using Flow?

Tags: python, powershell, powerapps, power-automate

I've made a PowerApps app which uploads an image to SharePoint. When Flow detects that this image is uploaded, I want to run a custom script that can interact with the Excel file. PowerShell should accomplish that, but I'm completely lost when it comes to running the PowerShell code from Flow.

My goal is to use an Excel macro to combine the image and an Excel file that is stored in the same location in SharePoint. PowerShell will execute the macro and delete the picture after.

I've found this guide "https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/flow-of-the-week-local-code-execution/", but I don't think it will work for me as the app will be running on more devices than just my local computer.

What technology can I use to run code using Flow as a trigger? The code must have access to a specific SharePoint site as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can create an [Azure Function that will execute PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell). This will execute from the cloud rather than on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to add a solution that worked great for me: Using Flow to send HTTP requests to a REST API!